# MySQL inner join with left outer join

Tags: mysql, join

I have 4 tables as below.

```
1. emp
    - emp_id
    - name
    - contact_id

2. contact
   - contact_id
   - name

3. emp_projects
   - prj_id
   - emp_id

4. project
   - prj_id
   - name
```

**Relationships :-**

> emp to projects - One to Many

I need a query joining all these tables.

**Conditions**

1. contact_id column in emp table can be empty so get contact details only if the column is not empty
2. Employee can be part of Zero or many projects.
3. Query needs to return the project name as well.

Query that I currently have,

select e.*,ep.* from emp e left outer join emp_projects ep on e.emp_id = ep.emp_id where  e.emp_id=1

Need to join contacts and projects table as well here.

Sample data,

```
1. emp

  | 1 | Mike | 1 |
  | 2 | John | - |

2. contact

  | 1 | Alex |

3. emp_projects

  | 1 | 1 |
  | 2 | 1 |

4. projects

  | 1 | Test |
  | 2 | Mail |
```

**Expected output :-**

For emp id 1,

```
    1(emp_id), Mike(emp_name), 1(contact_id), Alex(contact_name), 1(proj_id), Test(Prj_Name) 

   1(emp_id), Mike(emp_name), 1(contact_id), Alex(contact_name), 2(proj_id), Email(Prj_Name)
```

For emp id 2, ( Contact column is empty for emp 2 and emp 2 is not associated with any project )

1(emp_id), John(emp_name), -(contact_id), -(contact_name), -(proj_id), -(Prj_Name)

Comment: Please add sample data for all tables as well as the expected output.

Comment: What is `e.`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query and DDL script is added below. 1 recommendation, use the primary key in the mapping table or have a composite key ( emp_id, project_id )

```
select 
  employee.id as employee_id, 
  employee.name as employee_name, 
  contact.id as contact_id, 
  contact.name as contact_name, 
  project.id as project_id, 
  project.name as project_name
FROM employee employee
LEFT OUTER JOIN contact contact on contact.id = employee.contact_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_projects employee_project on employee_project.employee_id = employee.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN project project on project.id = employee_project.project_id 





CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` 
(   `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL
,   `contact_id` int(6) unsigned NULL
,   `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL
,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

INSERT INTO `employee` (`id`, `contact_id`, `name`) VALUES  
('1', '1', 'Mike'),
('2', null, 'John');   

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `contact`
(   `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL
,   `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL
,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

INSERT INTO `contact`
(`id`, `name`) VALUES   
('1', 'Alex');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project` 
(   `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL
,   `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL
,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

INSERT INTO `project` (`id`, `name`) VALUES   
('1','Test'),  
('2', 'Mail');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee_projects` 
(   `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL
,   `employee_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL
,   `project_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL
,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `employee_projects`
(`id`, `project_id`, `employee_id`) VALUES   
('1', '1', '1'),  
('2', '2', '1');
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with table aliases. And just to be aware that the number in parentheses following an int declaration is almost meaningless

Answer (score -1):

I think the below query will to the trick:

```
select e.,ep.,c.,p.
from emp e 
    left outer join emp_projects ep on e.emp_id = ep.emp_id
    left outer join contact c on c.emp_id = e.emp_id 
    left outer join project p on p.proj_id = ep.proj_id 
where e.emp_id=1
```

Comment: contact should be joined using contact_id and this id can be blank in emp table,